# Is this encryption method considered to be safe?

Tags: php, mysql, blowfish, crypt, password-hash

This is my encryption way that I've just made in php and with it I store my passwords in the data-base
this is my code for the login page

```
<?php
session_start();
require("db_connection.php");
require("functions.php");

if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    header("location: admin.php");
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if ($_POST['username']==""||$_POST['password']==""){
        header ("location: login.php");
    }

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['username']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $found_admin = attempt_login($username,$password);

    if($found_admin) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $found_admin['username'];
        $_SESSION['name'] = $found_admin['name'];
        header("location: admin.php");
    }else {
        $status =  "Please verify your credentials";
    }
}

?>
```

I have created the function in a separate file, can anyone here give me an advice to tweak this code
I'm only learning this language for about a week.
planning to start the Object Oriented php.
the functions are

```
function encrypt_password ($password){
    $hash_form = "$2y$10$";
    $salt_length = 22;
    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $form_and_salt = $hash_form . $salt;
    $hash = crypt($password,$form_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}

function generate_salt ($length){
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);
    $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.',$base64_string);
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string,0,$length);
    return $salt;
}

function password_check ($password, $existing_hash){
    $hash = crypt($password,$existing_hash);
    if($hash===$existing_hash){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

function find_admin_by_username($username){
    global $connect;
    $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username='{$safe_username}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect , $query);
    if($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $admin;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

function attempt_login($username, $password){
    $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
    if ($admin){
        if(password_check($password,$admin['password'])){
            return $admin;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I cannot comment and test too much your code but I can give you a good way to encrypt your passwords (used by wordpress).

Comment: can you give it to me please ?

Comment: It will be much better to use PHP's built-in password hashing functions than to write your own. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: This would be better on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

> is this encryption method considered to be safe?

No. Bcrypt is fine, but your implementation is dangerous.

---

Please remember that [you don't encrypt passwords, you hash them](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). The linked article explains the nuances regarding various cryptography terms and concepts. If nothing else, it should help [learn how to ask better questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) if you encounter cryptography in other areas down the line.

If you need to store passwords, use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) and [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify). **Do not write your own cryptography features unless you know what you are doing.**

WordPress should already include [password_compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) (which allows you to use the recommended functions in PHP 5.3.7+) but as of August 2015 you should already be on PHP 5.5 so this is a moot point.

If you're on an older version of PHP, pressure your web host to update to 5.5 or 5.6 immediately. You'll make the Internet a safer place if you do.

With the recommended functions (and replacing `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with prepared statements, which are the [correct and effective solution to SQL Injection](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/preventing-sql-injection-in-php-applications-easy-and-definitive-guide)), your code might look something like this:

```
function find_admin_by_username($username)
{
    global $connect;
    
    // Create a prepared statement with our query structure
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
    
    // Bind a string parameter (hence the "s"):
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
    
    // If the query was successful
    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        // Grab the result from the prepared statement...
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        
        // And then return a single row from the table
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
}

function attempt_login($username, $password)
{
    $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
    if ($admin) {
        if (password_verify($password, $admin['password'])) {
            return $admin;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

I'm going to go down the line and annotate (my comments prefixed with a `##`) your code.

```
function encrypt_password ($password){ ## You're hashing, not encrypting
    $hash_form = "$2y$10$"; ## Why is the cost of 10 hard-coded? Some people might want 11 or 12.
    $salt_length = 22; ## This doesn't need to be a variable
    $salt = generate_salt($salt_length);
    $form_and_salt = $hash_form . $salt; ## This is backwards
    $hash = crypt($password,$form_and_salt);
    return $hash;
}

function generate_salt ($length){
    $unique_random_string = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)); ## This is weak. See footnote
    $base64_string = base64_encode($unique_random_string);
    $modified_base64_string = str_replace('+', '.',$base64_string);
    $salt = substr($modified_base64_string,0,$length);
    return $salt;
}

function password_check ($password, $existing_hash){
    $hash = crypt($password,$existing_hash);
    if($hash===$existing_hash){ ## Timing side-channel (albeit not a practical one)
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

function find_admin_by_username($username){
    global $connect;
    
    ## Editing and concatenating strings fails more often than prepared statements.
    ## If you want to be conservative about security, get very familiar with
    ## mysqli_prepare() and friends. You can almost never have to use
    ## mysqli_real_escape_string() again if you're careful enough.
    $safe_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username='{$safe_username}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect , $query);
    if($admin = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        return $admin;
    }else{ ## You can just leave this outside the if block
        return null; ## If you don't return anything, null is returned
    }
}

function attempt_login($username, $password){
    $admin = find_admin_by_username($username);
    if ($admin){
        if(password_check($password,$admin['password'])){
            return $admin;
        }else { ## unnecessary
            return false; ## unnecessary
        }
    }else { ## unnecessary
        return false; ## unnecessary
    }
}
```

#### Footnote on `md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));`

> This is a weak random number generator and should never be used for anything related to cryptography.

I used weak random number generators to create a backdoored user authentication library in my winning entry for the [Underhanded Crypto Contest at DEFCON 23](https://underhandedcrypto.com/2015/08/08/crypto-privacy-village-contest-winners). The short of it is: If you're [generating a random string](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php) within a hundred miles of any cryptography utility, you need a [CSPRNG](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.csprng.php).

Please tell me who or what misled you into believing `md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));` is a secure random number generator. I've seen a lot of people make the same mistake and I'd like to stop the spread of bad cryptography advice. Is it a tutorial somewhere? I'd really like to correct it.

**To reiterate: `md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));` is not secure. Don't use it.**

### TL;DR

- Use the Password Hashing features that PHP gives you.
- Don't write your own cryptography.
- Don't use a weak random number generator.
- Use prepared statements instead of escaping.

Comment: I know that md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)); can't generate a 100% unique salt 
but at least I made some effort, as I said, I've only been 6 or 7 days in this language ! 
you are talking like I'm an expert cryptography engineer 
be easy on me ! 
but, to be honest, you made allot of things clear to me in this answer :D

Comment: It's a common mistake that I've seen repeated all over Stack Overflow (and sadly in production systems). I don't mean to overload you with information; rather, I'm interested in fixing it at its source but so far I've been unable to locate it. If you remember where you heard of this one-liner, please let me know. That said, I'm glad you found this illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

WpPasswordHash.php

```
<?php
#
# Portable PHP password hashing framework.
#
# Version 0.3 / genuine.
#
# Written by Solar Designer <solar at openwall.com> in 2004-2006 and placed in
# the public domain.  Revised in subsequent years, still public domain.
#
# There's absolutely no warranty.
#
# The homepage URL for this framework is:
#
#   http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
#
# Please be sure to update the Version line if you edit this file in any way.
# It is suggested that you leave the main version number intact, but indicate
# your project name (after the slash) and add your own revision information.
#
# Please do not change the "private" password hashing method implemented in
# here, thereby making your hashes incompatible.  However, if you must, please
# change the hash type identifier (the "$P$") to something different.
#
# Obviously, since this code is in the public domain, the above are not
# requirements (there can be none), but merely suggestions.
#
class WpPasswordHash {
    var $itoa64;
    var $iteration_count_log2;
    var $portable_hashes;
    var $random_state;

    function WpPasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
    {
        $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
            $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
        $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

        $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

        $random_state = microtime() . getmypid();
    }

    function get_random_bytes($count)
    {
        $output = '';
        if (($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
            $output = fread($fh, $count);
            fclose($fh);
        }

        if (strlen($output) < $count) {
            $output = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
                $this->random_state =
                    md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
                $output .=
                    pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
        }

        return $output;
    }

    function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $value = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_private($input)
    {
        $output = '$P$';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[min($this->iteration_count_log2 +
        ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);

        return $output;
    }

    function crypt_private($password, $setting)
    {
        $output = '*0';
        if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
            $output = '*1';

        if (substr($setting, 0, 3) != '$P$')
            return $output;

        $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
        if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
            return $output;

        $count = 1 << $count_log2;

        $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
        if (strlen($salt) != 8)
            return $output;

        # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
        # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
        # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
        # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
        # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
        # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
            $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
            do {
                $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
            } while (--$count);
        } else {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
            do {
                $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
            } while (--$count);
        }

        $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
        $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_extended($input)
    {
        $count_log2 = min($this->iteration_count_log2 + 8, 24);
        # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
        # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
        $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;

        $output = '_';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];

        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_blowfish($input)
    {
        # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
        # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
        # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
        # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
        # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
        # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
        # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
        # of entropy.
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        $output = '$2a$';
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 / 10);
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 % 10);
        $output .= '$';

        $i = 0;
        do {
            $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
            $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
            if ($i >= 16) {
                $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
                break;
            }

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);

        return $output;
    }

    function HashPassword($password)
    {
        $random = '';

        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 60)
                return $hash;
        }

        if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
            if (strlen($random) < 3)
                $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 20)
                return $hash;
        }

        if (strlen($random) < 6)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
        $hash =
            $this->crypt_private($password,
                $this->gensalt_private($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 34)
            return $hash;

        # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
        # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
        # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
        return '*';
    }

    function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
    {
        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
        if ($hash[0] == '*')
            $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

        return $hash == $stored_hash;
    }
}

?>
```

Then when you want to verify a password:
Separate php file:

```
$res = $this->_checkPassword($password, $res['User']['password']);

    private function _checkPassword($password, $hash) {
        $wp_hasher = new WpPasswordHash(8, true);
        $hashed_password = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);

        return $hashed_password;
    }
```

For encryption:

```
private function _encryptPwd($password) {
    $wp_hasher = new WpPasswordHash(8, true);
    $hashed_password = $wp_hasher->HashPassword($password);

    return $hashed_password;
}
```

Comment: I've understood it a bit 
but since I haven't started at Object Oriented Php 
some points still not clear to me

I'm planning to learn Obj. Or php later

Comment: Great let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I haven't slept well this week since I'm learning php ! 
it's only 6 days until now ! 
I have no idea about php
only few basics in The C language helped me allot ! 

but I think that obj or. is a far way harder than procedural php

Comment: Yes opp, but easy to understand I think if you used C :D

Comment: `return $hash == $stored_hash;` - [seems legit](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/36732/hacking/php-hash-comparison-flaw.html)